# Finding segfault without having testing data

Tags: c++, debugging, testing, segmentation-fault

This might seem like a stupid question, but I need to know, if there is any tool for finding possible segfault points in my code without having the testing data, that cause the segfault. Especially some tool for testing correct using of pointers to items in an array

Comment: [Static code analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_code_analysis) might help finding _some_ problems.

Comment: I run [`cppcheck`](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) as part of my build process.

Comment: If you're afraid of a section of your code, you can write specific unit tests just for that. I tend to write units tests for all my code (c:, and my fear is reduced.

Comment: cppcheck couldn't find it either. But I made a fuzzy test in bash and finally located the bug. I reallocated array of data, but I forgot to change sorted pointers, that pointed to those data. It segfaulted only with large data, that needed reallocation. Stupid mistake :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options in general:

- code reviews (not a tool in the sense of being a computer program, but a tool nonetheless)
- static code analyzers
- fuzz tests

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for heading me in these directions. Had no idea especially about the last two tools. Should solve my problem :)

Comment: Be advised that static code analyzers may be unable to find all flaws and they can even produce false positives and that the quality of fuzz testing depends a lot on the code and on the tests. You should consider running fuzz tests on code-coverage-instrumented executables so you can see unexercised spots of the code and write missing tests.

Answer (score 1):

A very good option is [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)'s [MemCheck](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#memcheck). It is likely that there are invalid memory accesses (dangling pointers, reads from uninitialized variables, buffer overflows, heap corruption, ...) even with data that does not immediately cause a segmentation fault. This will point them out as they happen instead of waiting for a segmentation fault that may occur only very far from the problem itself, allowing you to fix them.

Comment: Memcheck couldn't locate the error, but that might be just a coincidence. Thanks for the tip :)